# Vote count missing in Close votes "off-topic because" dialog

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, close-dialog

The vote count for the off-topic reasons is missing in the close votes queue. Example:

[image]

But after clicking on "off-topic because...":

[image]

The count(s) for the off-topic votes should show on the second dialog. They did until at least yesterday sometime, so this appears to be broken by the "fuzzing" of the close votes queue that just took place.

Comment: When was the question first asked?

Comment: October 26, 2013.

Comment: The off-topic *reasons* changed just a couple months ago, so older close votes don't show next to any of the new reasons

Comment: Ah... that probably explains it. I keep forgetting how long some questions must have languished there...

Comment: yeah, they finally get their come-uppance. **burn baby burn!**

Comment: At least the queue's moving in the right direction again!

Comment: @hims056 You are correct; I looked, but didn't find that one for some reason.